# What is the java equivalent of AggregateException from .net?

Tags: java, .net, exception

In .net the AggregateException class allows you to throw an exception containing multiple exceptions.

For example, you would want to throw an AggregateException if you ran multiple tasks in parallel and some of them failed with exceptions.

Does java have an equivalent class?

The specific case I want to use it in:

```
public static void runMultipleThenJoin(Runnable... jobs) {
    final List<Exception> errors = new Vector<Exception>();
    try {
        //create exception-handling thread jobs for each job
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (final Runnable job : jobs)
            threads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {public void run() {
                try {
                    job.run();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    errors.add(ex);
                }
            }}));

        //start all
        for (Thread t : threads)
            t.start();

        //join all
        for (Thread t : threads)
            t.join();            
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        //no way to recover from this situation
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    if (errors.size() > 0)
        throw new AggregateException(errors); 
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of one.  However, I've never looked for one either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built-in or library classes, as I've never even though of wanting to do this before (typically you would just chain the exceptions), but it wouldn't be that hard to write yourself.

You'd probably want to pick one of the Exceptions to be "primary" so it can be used to fill in stacktraces, etc.

```
public class AggregateException extends Exception {

    private final Exception[] secondaryExceptions;

    public AggregateException(String message, Exception primary, Exception... others) {
        super(message, primary);
        this.secondaryExceptions = others == null ? new Exception[0] : others;
    }

    public Throwable[] getAllExceptions() {

        int start = 0;
        int size = secondaryExceptions.length;
        final Throwable primary = getCause();
        if (primary != null) {
            start = 1;
            size++;
        }

        Throwable[] all = new Exception[size];

        if (primary != null) {
            all[0] = primary;
        }

        Arrays.fill(all, start, all.length, secondaryExceptions);
        return all;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12):

Java 7's [Throwable.addSuppressed(Throwable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed%28java.lang.Throwable%29) will do something similar, although it was built for a slightly different purpose ([try-with-resource](http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/OCPJP-OCAJP-Java-7-Suppressed-Exceptions-Try-With-Resources))

Answer (score 1):

You can represent multiple taska as

```
List<Callable<T>> tasks
```

Then if you want the computer to actually do them in parallel use

```
ExecutorService executorService = .. initialize executor Service
List<Future<T>> results = executorService.invokeAll ( ) ;
```

Now you can iterate through the results.

```
try
{
     T val = result . get ( ) ;
}
catch ( InterruptedException cause )
{
     // this is not the exception you are looking for
}
catch ( ExecutionExeception cause )
{
     Throwable realCause = cause . getCause ( ) // this is the exception you are looking for
}
```

So realCause (if it exists) is whatever exception what thrown in its associated task.

Comment: It's nice to see that there are already ways to run tasks concurrently. However, your solution doesn't address throwing an exception representing multiple task failures.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see why you should use exceptions in the first place to mark tasks as incomplete/failed but in any case, it shouldn't be hard to create one yourself. Got any code to share so that we could help you with a more specific answer?

Comment: I'm not using it to 'mark' anything, I just want to indicate at-least-one-failure. I've edited the main post to include code.

Comment: One example this is useful is for validation. Instead of throwing exception on the first invalid property, validate the entire class so the consumer can understand why the payload is invalid.  This is a much nicer way to discover an API.