# Throwing Multiple Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, extends, custom-exceptions

I have a Java Application code that has following custom Exception structure

- `SettlementException` extends `Exception`
- `PolicyMissingException` extends `SettlementException`
- `PolicyExpiredException` extends `SettlementException`

I have some try/catch blocks in the code that try `PolicyMissing` and `PolicyExpired` and throw the same.

```
try
{
    if (Policy != null)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        throw new PolicyMissingException(“Policy missing”);
    }
}
catch(PolicyMissingException e)
{
  e.printstacktrace();
}
```

Is there any way I can throw `SettlementException` too besides `PolicyMissing` and `PolicyExpired` along with them?

Comment: you can catch multiple exceptions - just add another catch block below your **catch(PolictMissingExc)** block

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374966/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-aggregateexception-from-net

Comment: You mean throwing one of the two exceptions depending on the circumstances? Sure, you can.  Just use if-else-if-else.  Or do you mean throwing two exceptions *at the same time*?  Sorry, you cannot do that.  Maybe make a new exception class that combines the information you want to convey.

Comment: @jbutler483 You can also use a multiple catch block: **`catch(FirstException | SecondException e)`**

Comment: @msrd0 I was thinking more of if the OP wanted to catch/do something differently on each of the 'throws'

Comment: I think that he is looking a Java version of a AggregateException in c#

Comment: @jbutler483 I think its very unclear what the OP wants to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should allow you to catch all three exceptions, and do something with each one. Also note, the order of the 'catches' is important too (see comment below this post)

```
try
{
    if(Policy!=null)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        throw new PolicyMissingExc(“Policy missing”);
    }
}
catch(PolicyMissingExc e)
{
  e.printstacktrace();
}
catch(PolicyExpired c)
{
  //catch c here
}
catch(SettlementException b)
{
  //catch b here
}
```

Comment: If you do this, just be sure that if one exception is derived from (extends) another one, put the most-derived type first or it will never be caught.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    if(Policy!=null)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        throw new PolicyMissingExc(“Policy missing”);
    }
}
catch(PolicyMissingExc e)
{
  e.printstacktrace();
}
catch(PolicyExpired e)
{
  e.printstacktrace();
}
catch(SettlementException e)
{
  e.printstacktrace();
}
```

You can catch multiple exceptions but remember catch block must be in order from subclass to superclass otherwise you will get Unreachable catch block compilation error.

Comment: My policymissing and policyexpired exceptions are classes that extend settlementException. The way you have provided gives unreachable catch block error for settlementException. Saying only specific exceptions are thrown and handles by previous catch blocks

Comment: I mean you cannot catch SettlementException before its subclasses PolicyMissingExc or PolicyExpired.

Comment: Yeah. Understood.  That is why the code first catches policyExpired. But I want both to be caught, policyExpired and settlement. Which is not happening

Answer (score 0):

Why not have just one exception class, SettlementException, and use it as a container (Set?) for all of the known problems?